# Matrix product state representation for the "infinitely repulsive hardcore boson" state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, spin-chains, tensor-network

Consider a one-dimensional spin-1/2 chain with $N$ spins, and let $|\psi\rangle$ be the equal weight superposition of all states with no adjacent spin-ups, e.g.
for $N=3$ with open-boundary, $|\psi_{N=3}\rangle=|000\rangle+|001\rangle+|010\rangle+|100\rangle+|101\rangle,$ up to a normalization factor. How to construct a [MPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_product_state) representation for $|\psi\rangle$?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thanks, I have just edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to construct the MPS tensor such that it mediates the structure of your state through the virtual indices: If the physical state is $\vert1\rangle$, you want to choose the virtual state to the left and right such as to signal that, to avoid having another $\vert1\rangle$ state next to it.

One option would be to force the virtual state on the left to $0$ and on the right to $1$ if the physical state is $\vert1\rangle$: Then, it is impossible to have two $\vert1\rangle$'s adjacent to each other. On the other hand, a physical $\vert0\rangle$ should be compatible with *both* options, and thus treat a virtual $0$ or $1$ the same way.

This leads to a MPS tensor with
$$
A^0=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1 &1\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix}=\vert+\rangle\langle+|\ ,
\quad 
A^1=\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=(\sqrt{2}\vert0\rangle)(\langle1\vert\sqrt{2})\ .
$$
Clearly, $A^1A^1=0$, and thus, no two $1$'s can be adjacent to each other. On the other hand, any other configuration is admissible. More importantly - and this is how I chose the normalization (which I did in retrospect) - all configurations have the same weight (for periodic boundary conditions), since
$$
\langle+\vert+\rangle = 
\sqrt{2}\langle1\vert+\rangle = 
\sqrt{2}\langle+\vert0\rangle\ .
$$
The same works for an open boundary condition MPS, if you choose left and right boundary conditions $\vert+\rangle$.